# How to get default behavior in react input onKeyDown event?

Tags: html, reactjs, input, onkeydown

I have an input element in where I am capturing keyboard events.

```
onKeyDown={(e) => {
     if (e.key === "ArrowDown") {
         console.log("pressed down arrow");
     } else if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
         console.log("pressed up arrow");
     } else if (e.key === "Enter") {
         console.log("pressed enter");
     } else {
         how do I get default behavior for the rest of the keys? 
         Ex: backspace
         When backspace is pressed, it is not deleting the characters from the input box
     }
}}
```

Here is the sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-gwen-z4oqfi?file=/src/App.js) for the same

Comment: Unable to reproduce, backspace is removing chars from the input.

Comment: Yes, I think I messed up something else. Thank you.